# Need to select only one classification out of multiple values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of clients, products and their classifications in a Pivot Table

```
(Client Number)       (Products)      (Classifications)  
--------1-----------------A---------------High  
--------2-----------------B---------------Medium  
--------3-----------------C---------------**Medium**  
--------3-----------------B---------------**Low**   
--------3-----------------B---------------**High**
```

I'll like to show only the Highest classification per client (*ie. Client 3 should only be High*)

I do not want to list multiple results (using Index and Small) as presentation of the data is important. Ideally this can be done and shown in a single column (even better if it can be done in the "Classifications" Column itself.

```
(Client Number)       (Products)      (Classifications)  (Overall)  
--------1-----------------A---------------High-----------High  
--------2-----------------B---------------Medium-------Medium   
--------3-----------------C---------------**Medium**------**High**  
--------3-----------------B---------------**Low**   
--------3-----------------B---------------**High**
```

Alternatively if there is way for me to arrange my pivot table to find the solution, that works too.

Note that the "**Classifications**" Row is not a part of the pivot table, but a *nested IF Formula* that calculates the classification based on a complicated criteria. There are only 3 classifications to be considered.

Comment: Show us the formula you tried